# replace specific string in a txt file, but only in certain lines

Tags: python, replace, txt

txt file with 40000 lines. In each lines are comma seperated numbers. I want to remove a specific number in the lines 36000 to 39000. For example number 233. But i dont want to remove the string from number 23341.

Here is my code so far:

```
with open("example.txt","r") as file:
newline =[]
i = 0
for l in file.readlines():
    if i>=36000 and i<=39000:
         newline.append(word.replace("233",""))
    else:
         newline.append(word.replace("233","233"))
    i = i + 1

with open("example.txt","w") as file:
for line in newline:
    f.writelines(line)
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe you can use regex for it? import re

with open("example.txt","r") as file:
    newline = []
    i = 0
    for l in file.readlines():
        if i >= 36000 and i <= 39000:
            newline.append(re.sub(r"\b233\b", "", l))
        else:
            newline.append(l)
        i += 1

with open("example.txt","w") as file:
    for line in newline:
        file.write(line)

Comment: If your numbers are comma separated, is it possible to replace by "233,", comma included ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a large text file with appending each line into a list to further overwrite the whole file - is definitely inefficient approach, use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) module and precompiled (with [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)) regex pattern instead:

```
import fileinput, re

with fileinput.input('example.txt', inplace=True, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'\b233\b')
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 36000 and i <= 39000:
            line = pat.sub('', line)
        print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex replacement here:

```py
for line in file.readlines():
    if i >= 36000 and i <= 39000:
        line = re.sub(r',?\b233\b,?', ',', line).strip(',')
        newline.append(line)
    i = i + 1
```

The above regex logic targets specifically the value `233` as a CSV value.  The pattern and replacement ensure that the resulting CSV has no empty values or dangling commas.